# Java: How capturing pen data in Wacom STU-530 Tablet?

Tags: java, wacom

I'm trying to capture all the pen data: touch, pressure at one point, coordinates of the touch ...

Any suggestions?

```
SigCtl sigCtl = new SigCtl();
DynamicCapture dc = new DynamicCapture();
int rc = dc.capture(sigCtl, "who", "why", null, null);
if(rc == 0) {
    System.out.println("signature captured successfully");
    String fileName = "sig1.png";
    SigObj sig = sigCtl.signature();
    sig.extraData("AdditionalData", "CaptureImage.java Additional Data");

    int flags = SigObj.outputFilename | SigObj.color32BPP | SigObj.encodeData;
    sig.renderBitmap(fileName, 200, 150, "image/png", 0.5f, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, 0.0f, 0.0f, flags );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using the wgssStu library, this jar there is PenData class, which has the following methods: getPressure, getX, getY, getRdy, getSw...

Comment: Hi there, Im trying to connect to the wacom 300 using java, but I cant find the jar you specified in you comment. Where can I download that jar?

Comment: where can we find the jar file @The apprentice